# filteredArrayUsingPredicate does not exist in swift Array

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I have "UserDetails" struct objects in array..I want to filter the objects from array. But there is no option for "filteredArrayUsingPredicate" in Swift array.

My array creation

```
var arrayOfUsers:UserDetails[] = UserDetails[]()
```

my userdetails code is

```
struct UserDetails{
    var userName:String
    var userID:String
    var userAge:String
    func userDescription()->String{
        return "name " + userName + "age " + userID
    }
}
```

my code to create objects

```
        for a in 1...1000{
            var user:UserDetails = UserDetails(userName: "name", userID: String(a), userAge: "22")
            arrayOfUsers.append(user)
        }
```

Now I want to filter `arrayOfUsers` which one has userID "1".

Comment: BEEP! iOS 8 is beta, and XCode 6 too.

Comment: so cant i filter with beta version? i am new to iOS,please make me correct if i did anything wrong..

Comment: @Manimurugan nicael's point was that you have agreed to not discuss Apple's betas in public. I am not sure if this is applicable here, though, because Swift book and library reference are released to the public with no strings attached.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Swift arrays have a `.filter` method that takes a closure -- this will do it:

```
let filteredArray = arrayOfUsers.filter() { $0.userID == "1" }
```

Closures can be simplified in a variety of ways. The full declaration of the closure would look more like this:

```
var filteredArray = arrayOfUsers.filter( { (user: UserDetails) -> Bool in
        return user.userID == "1"
    })
```

The difference between the two is that the first is using trailing closure syntax, shorthand argument names, type inference, and implicit return. You can read [more about closures in Apple's Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Closures.html).

Comment: can you please tell me about $ symbol..what is the use of this ?

Comment: `$0` is a shorthand argument name. I'll add a bit more detail.

Comment: if it is array of dictionaries,then how can i implement predicate to filter data for userID == 1(if user id is the key of Dictionary) ?

Comment: That's a little trickier, since subscripting a dictionary returns an Optional. You'd want to get the value from the dictionary, make sure it exists, then see if it's "1" and return true, false otherwise.

Comment: @Manimurugan refer my answer

Comment: i am using swift 1.2, it doesnt have method named `filter`, instead it have `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` method, but not working properly

Comment: Prettiest solution so far! Swift syntax is so light and convenient, thx Nate

Comment: NSPredicate vs Pure Swift filter, which is a better (faster, scalable ) solution ?

Answer (score 108):

you can also use NSPredicate

```
    var customerNameDict = ["firstName":"karthi","LastName":"alagu","MiddleName":"prabhu"];
    var clientNameDict = ["firstName":"Selva","LastName":"kumar","MiddleName":"m"];
    var employeeNameDict = ["firstName":"karthi","LastName":"prabhu","MiddleName":"kp"];
    var attributeValue = "karthi";

    var arrNames:Array = [customerNameDict,clientNameDict,employeeNameDict];


    var namePredicate =
        NSPredicate(format: "firstName like %@",attributeValue);

    let filteredArray = arrNames.filter { namePredicate.evaluateWithObject($0) };
    println("names = ,\(filteredArray)");
```

//struct filtering

```
struct myStruct
{
    var userid:String;
    var details:String;
    init() {
        userid = "default value";
        details = "default";
    }

};
var f1 = myStruct();
f1.userid = "1";
f1.details = "Good boy";

var f2 = myStruct();
f2.userid = "2";
f2.details = "Bad boy";
var arrNames1:Array = [f1,f2];
let filteredArrayStruct =  arrNames1.filter( { (user: myStruct) -> Bool in
    return user.userid == "1"
    })
println("filter array count = \(filteredArrayStruct.count)");
for  filteredValues in filteredArrayStruct
{
       println("filteredArrayStruct = ,\(filteredValues.details)");
}
```

Comment: @karthik Prabhu 

What would you do if you have an array of structs rather than an array of dictionaries?

`let filteredArray = arrNames.filter { namePredicate.evaluateWithObject($0) };`

That line is giving me the error "Type 'myStruct' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'"

Comment: I like your solution more because NSPredicates are way more powerful than simple string comparisons. Only the possibility to compare case insensitive in an easy way: `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "description contains[c] %@", argumentArray: [searchText])`

Comment: awesome! Was looking for this. This is really helpful when you're doing a ObjectiveC to swift conversion and don't really want to touch the predicate logic.

Answer (score 5):

If you are filtering a dictionary you can do it like this.

```
var visitors = [["age" : 22], ["age" : 41], ["age" : 23], ["age" : 30]]

var filteredVisitors = visitors.filter({
    $0["age"] < 30
})

println(filteredVisitors)
//[["age" : 22], ["age" : 23]]
```

Well the same applies to structs where you would filter its property

```
struct Person {
    var age : Int?
    init(age: Int) {
        self.age = age
    }
}

var eventAttendees = [Person(age: 22), Person(age: 41), Person(age: 23), Person(age: 30)]

var filteredAttendees = eventAttendees.filter({
    $0.age < 30
})
```

You can refer to this articles for more info. [Filtering a Swift Array of Dictionaries or Object property](http://locomoviles.com/ios-tutorials/filtering-swift-array-dictionaries-object-property/)

Answer (score 2):

**In swift 3 or 4** you can use **NSPredicate** With **Array**

```
let pred : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "points_status = %@", "0")
let   approvalRequestArray =  approvalRequestOriginalArray.filtered(using: pred) as NSArray


let provincesStartingWithM = NSPredicate(format: "name contains [cd] 'a'")

provinces.filtered(using: provincesStartingWithM)
```

For More information, You can Visit this link
[GitHub](https://github.com/dfreniche/NSPredicate-Swift)

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, you don't have to compare only one filter at a time. You can apply logical conditionals to broaden the scope of the predicate. For example:

```
var foundArray = tempArray.filter{ String(describing:$0.id) .contains(searchText) || 
$0.name .contains(searchText) || $0.summary! .contains(searchText) || 
String(describing: $0.airDate).contains(searchText) || String(describing: $0.airTime).contains(searchText) || 
String(describing: $0.runTime).contains(searchText)}
```

works like a champ.