# NSPredicate to find UIView with same tag form self.view.subviews Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, predicate

I want to find UIViews with tag 1 in one array from self.superview?.subviews but I am getting error **value of type [UIView] has no member filteredArrayUsingPredicate.**

```
//This is my code
   let predicate:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "self.tag == 1")
   var arrFilteredVw = []
   if(self.superview?.subviews.count>0){
        arrFilteredVW = self.superview?.subviews.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
   }
```

My simple question is I don't want to use `for in` loop here how to do it with predicate.

Comment: Why don't you use `viewWithTag`?

Comment: maybe you can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/24382771/5084564

Comment: viewWithTag will give me the first view with tag 1 that is finds in superview

Comment: Why don't you want to use `for in` exactly?

Comment: well I have to use two loops than first to filter the views with tag 1 than some logic of mine on that array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` is defined as an extension on `NSArray` and not Swifts `Array` (`[UIView]` in your case).

In Swift you can achieve the same thing this way :

```
var arrFilteredVw = []
if(self.superview?.subviews.count>0){
    arrFilteredVW = self.superview?.subviews.filter { (subview) -> Bool in
        return subview.tag == 1
    }
}
```

Comment: And functional nature of Swift :) Glad I could help!