# How to filter data that has been fetched from Core Data?

Tags: swift, core-data, filter

Fetching from Core Data, I can filter what I get by using NSPredicate, but only by using persistent attributes, but not transient attributes ([as per this article from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspropertydescription)). What method(s) can be used to further filter the data using Transient Attributes or some sort of computed property?

(This question is a refinement of [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314505/where-to-put-code-defining-a-transient-attribute-filtering-on-transient-attri), which was overly broad.)

Comment: Simply iterate over your fetched results and take the objects that fit your filter criteria, using common techniques like `for` loop, `.filer` or such.

Comment: @shallowThought - Many thanks -- that was the hint I needed.  My results are reproduced below on the chance that others may be where I was at and will find this useful, but it's your answer that got me looking in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to @shallowThought, the answer is fairly straightforward:

Having set up my predicates, the filtering uses the following line of code:

```
filteredLines = theLines.filter {myPredicate.evaluate(with: ($0))}
```

In this case, theLines is what was retrieved from CoreData, and myPredicate is whatever I want to filter on, such as

```
    let p1 = NSPredicate(format: "lineNumber > 4")  
    let p2 = NSPredicate(format: "lineNumber < 7")  
//        let minLineNumberStr = "4"
//        let p3 = NSPredicate(format: "lineNumber >= %@", minLineNumberStr) // same as p1, but more flexible

    var predArray : [NSPredicate] = []

// Comment out the predicates we DON'T actually use:
        predArray.append(p1)
        predArray.append(p2)
//        predArray.append(p3)

    let myPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: predArray)
```

In this case, if the predicate contains a transient attribute, the filtering works as expected (i.e. the transient attribute is evaluated correctly); when fetching from core data, the filter with a transient property does NOT throw an error, but it also returns no results.

Resources that helped my arrive at this answer:

- From We-Heart-Swift.com: ["Higher Order Functions: Map, Filter, Reduce, and More](https://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/)
- Stack Overflow article: [filteredArrayUsingPredicate does not exist in swift Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382580/filteredarrayusingpredicate-does-not-exist-in-swift-array) (first two answers)

Hope this is helpful to others with the same question I had.