# Implementing sort/filter in tableview controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view controller and thinking about implementing a filter where the user would click on the segmented controller and get results filtered by a specific parameter. I found many answers and tutorials for Search Bar and Scope Button Titles... I actually don't need search bar just scope button titles. What would be the best solution to implement something like segmented controller for filtering table view? Is it possible to implement scope buttons without scope?

Comment: Decide the data to load on table view based on selected segment index. You can take only one tableview and reload data based on segment index. Your approach is correct. You don't need search bar for this requirement. You can use segment index

Comment: @Kirillc you meant just what select query with where clause does?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out best implementation of the filter, since I don't need a search bar just buttons. I can figure out the query, need to know if it's possible to have just buttons.

Comment: @Kirillc check this -: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382580/filteredarrayusingpredicate-does-not-exist-in-swift-array

Comment: that's not what I'm asking